# SharePoint 365 permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, inheritance

I have created a SharePoint site which users need my approval to access. I have also created a document library within the site.  I would like to restrict folders for some users.

For example, I created a document library called CARS. Within the CARS folder, I have created FORD, BMW & VW subfolders.

What I would like to do is for the MD to access the Cars folder and subfolders Inside. James who works for VW to only access the VW subfolder & Jane who works for Ford to only access the Ford subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on `...` next to the folder.
2. In the List Item menu, click on `...` again.
3. Click on `Shared With`.
4. Click on `Advanced`
5. Click on `Stop Inheriting Permissions`
6. Edit the permissions as wanted.

**Additional tip**: Try to use a group instead of a user in the permissions. (E.g.: Put the permissions in Ford folder on the group "Ford Editors" instead of Jane) This will be easier to maintain in case you need to add/remove people to the folders permissions later.

**Source:** [Change the permissions on a subfolder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427BD7C-F20A-4F75-8CF2-5359DD45A1A6)

Answer (score 1):

Stop inheriting the permissions after stopping you can delete the user and groups and you can give permissions to users to specific folder or files however you want

[image]